# How to convert from bitset back to int

Tags: c++, file-io, huffman-code, bitset

So I currently working on file compression so to compress the file I am converting my string of ints using huffman encoding

example:

> 1000011011010100011010100010001101111001001111010011000011011100001010010110011011
> 1001110011111000010110110101111111

to bit set like this :

```
int i = 0;
while (i < str.length())
{
    bitset<8>set(str.substr(i, i + 7));
    outputFile << char(set.to_ulong());
    i = i + 8;
}
```

when I am retrieving the contents of that file I cant figure out how to convert it back to a  string of ints. Once i get back the string of ints I can retrieve the original contents I encoded its just getting the string back thats the problem

Comment: a string of ints in decimal?

Comment: Are you aware that the second argument of `substr` is the length of the substring? It seems to me that you quickly pass way more data than you intend to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question here is what you can do to perform a reversed operation:

```
constexpr int bits_num = sizeof(unsigned char) * CHAR_BIT; //somewhere upper in the file
//...

std::string outputStr;
unsigned char c;
while (inputFile.get(c))  //the simplest function to read "character by character"
{
    std::bitset<bits_num> bset(c);  //initialize bitset with a char value
    outputStr += bset.to_string();  //append to output string
}
```

Of course I assume that `inputFile` stream you will declare and set up for yourself.

`sizeof(unsigned char) * CHAR_BIT` is an elegant way of expressing a number of bits in a variables's type (like here `unsigned char`). To use the constant `CHAR_BIT` (which is basically `8` on all modern architectures) add `#include <climits>` header.

---

You have also an error in your code:

```
bitset<8>set(str.substr(i, i + 7));
```

You're increasing the cut out substring each iteration (`i + 7`), change it simply to `8` (or better and less error-prone to the suggested constant):

```
constexpr int bits_num = sizeof(unsigned char) * CHAR_BIT;

    //...
    std::bitset<bits_num> set( str.substr(i, bits_num) );
    outputFile << static_cast<unsigned char>( set.to_ulong() );
    i += bits_num;
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what im looking for, its partially working. The orignal string I encoded was This is the text in my input file , but now it reads  t fs is the text in my input fif e so something is going wrong im just nor sure where